# HTML Background (in one line)

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and I have a 2 questions which I couldn't find on google (all the properties have to be in one line);

1) I would like to "strech" a element with it's margin; e.g. 10px from left and right.

2) I would like to set the background-, foregound-, and borderbrush color.

This is what I tried (doesn't work):

```
<p style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px; position:absolute; background-color:#E0E0E0;"><input type="button" name="bt" value="Button" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"><br>
```

Comment: It doesnt work because of the absolute positioning

Comment: Well, if I delete it, it just streches something which looks like the shadow of the button, but the button itself keeps it's with

Comment: What element do you want to stretch? The input element or the wrapped p? Btw. you did not closed the p.

Comment: I would like to edit the inputelement.

Comment: but this also doesn't work: <input type="button" name="No Name" value="Button" style="width: 75px; height: 75px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px; position:relative; background-color:#E0E0E0;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I recommend placing your styles in a stylesheet and out of your HTML document.

The way I would make something full width is to do something like this in my stylesheet:

```
input {
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can change the width to be however wide you want it (80%, 25%).  The left, right, and margin make it centered on the screen.  This is fully responsive so it will work no matter the size screen.

Since you have styles inline here's what it would look like inline:

`<input style="display: block; width: 95%; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto; type="button" name="bt" value="Button" >`

Responsive Note:

In some cases you also want to consider the biggest screen size and add a `max-width` for those on large screens. Something like this:

```
input {
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 56rem;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
;
```

This would make it 95% until it reaches 56rem width and then it stays that big.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cheap solution to your first question.  will vary for each screen.

```
<p style="padding: 10px; width:97%; height:95%; position:absolute; background-color:#E0E0E0;"><input type="button" name="bt" value="Button" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></p>
```

Comment: This also doesn't strech the button but it's "shadow"